# Trying to use different pipelineStages for prod and dev in sbt-web

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.3, sbt-web

I have a project using Play Framework 2.3 and I'm having some issues with how JS files are handled throughout the asset pipeline. I want to process my JS source files differently depending on if the application is started in dev or prod mode. Specifically, I wan't to run pipeline stages called `transpile` and `watch` in dev mode but stages `transpile` and `uglify` in prod mode.

I've set up the global pipeline stages with `pipelineStages := Seq(transpile, uglify)` and this runs only in prod mode, as expected.

Now, for dev mode I've set it up with `pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(transpile, watch)` which works for dev but my problem is that this also runs in prod mode. The `watch` needs to only run in dev mode.

I haven't been able to find much good information on this, the [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Home) doesn't even mention `pipelineStages in Assets` and the [sbt-web](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-web) readme only mentions it in passing. Other than that I've only found a bunch of blog posts. From what I've read I got the impression that `pipelineStages in Assets` was exclusive to dev mode but that assumption was evidently incorrect.

I understand that `playRunHooks` is what is meant for dev exclusive stuff but afaik I can't use that for this since it runs after the configuration has been finalized and therefore can't be used to conditionally configure the pipeline stages.
My current, **extremely** ugly workaround for this problem is that I set a system property in `playRunHooks` and have a wrapper around the `watch` pipeline stage that checks this property when it gets invoked.

So is there any proper way to specify *'dev-only'* pipeline stages for my sbt-web build? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

(We're also in the process of migrating to Play Framework 2.6, in case that gives me more possibilities)

Comment: I faced the same issue but didn't any answer. If you or someone else has suggestions on this issue please post.